# Determination of the thermal resistance of a molding tool with cooling channel

Tags: thermodynamics, electrical-resistance, simulations, convection

This is a section of cooling channels in injection moulding tools.

[image] [image]

I have tried to calculate the thermal resistance in this section with 2 methods, one analytical and one numerical.

1. analytical solution:

I have calculated the thermal resistance by this equation

[image]

2. numerical
   there I have the difficulties, I vary the T1 and T2 and I read out the heat flows from ANSYS.
   What I can't understand is, which heat flow should I take (on the wall? or on the channel? in the middle?), because the heat flow is not constant in the part.

[image]

Many thanks

Comment: What is painted in color?

Comment: This is a transient problem, right?

Comment: @ChetMiller Yes, it's a transit analysis.

Comment: @AlexTrounev do you mean the last painting?

Comment: @ZouhirBensebban There is one color drawing - something with many holes. Is this a tool section?

Comment: @AlexTrounev yes this is the complete tool, but I am only analyzing a section (last picture) of it.

Comment: @ZouhirBensebban From above you set $T1= 200C$. What boundary conditions did you specify on the left, right, and bottom of the hole?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I have defined right and left as symmetry.
at the lower end as adiabatic, since we are dealing with a semi-infinite body.

Comment: @ZouhirBensebban What initial data did you set?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I have defined the boundary condition as symmetry to the left and right side in ANSYS.

Answer (score 0):

A numerical solution to the problem $\nabla ^2 T=0$ with boundary conditions $T=T1=200C$ at the upper boundary and $T=T2=40C$ at the boundary of the hole is shown in Figure 1 on the left, and the heat flux at the upper boundary $\dot {q}=-\vec {n}.\lambda \nabla T$ at $\lambda = 1$ on the right. To find the thermal resistance, we calculate the integral 
$$\dot {Q}=\int_0^b \dot {q}dx$$
[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer.
how did you get this curve? through Matlab? 
i first have to simplify dot {q} to calculate this integral

Comment: I used FEM and Mathematica 12.

Comment: Hello, Alex,
is the integral with the separation of the variable solvable?
I have followed the steps in the book "Fundamentals of Heat and Mass Transfer by Theodore L. Bergman" on pages 211-214, but I am confused when it comes to inserting constants.